# mapping multiple lists to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, mapping

I have 5 lists and I want to map them to a hierarchical dictionary.

let's say i have:

```
temp = [25, 25, 25, 25]
volt = [3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8]
chan = [1,1,6,6]
rate = [12,14,12,14]
power = [13.2,15.3,13.8,15.1]
```

and what I want as my dictionary is this:

```
{25:{3.8:{1:{12:13.2,14:15.3},6:{12:13.8,14:15.1}}}}
```

Basically the dictionary structure is:

```
{temp:{volt:{chan:{rate:power}}}}
```

I tried using the zip function but it does not help in this case because of the repeated values in the list at the top level

Comment: How do you handle the repeated values?

Comment: I just wanted to keep the list small in the example but my data will include for example: temp = [25,25,....,25,60,60,.....,60,75,75,...]

The only reason I have these repeated values is because the power values correspond to that temp value...I have no use for the list once it is mapped to a dict.

Comment: it is determined by the index. As an example for index = 2, temp = 25, volt = 3.8, chan = 1, rate = 14, power = 15.3

Answer (score 8):

This is only slightly tested, but it seems to do the trick. Basically, what `f` does, is to create a `defaultdict` of `defaultdicts`.

```
f = lambda: collections.defaultdict(f)
d = f()
for i in range(len(temp)):
    d[temp[i]][volt[i]][chan[i]][rate[i]] = power[i]
```

Example:

```
>>> print d[25][3.8][6][14]
15.1
```

(The idea is borrowed from [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12414913/1639625).)

Comment: I like to call these ``infinitedict = lambda: collections.defaultdict(infinitedict)``

Comment: @jterrace Yes, it was actually one of your answers that inspired me. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following ... I believe it serves what you want

```
>>> # Given your sample data.
>>> ans = {}
>>> for (t, v, c, r, p) in zip(temp, volt, chan, rate, power):
...     if not t in ans:
...             ans[t] = {}
...     if not v in ans[t]:
...             ans[t][v] = {}
...     if not c in ans[t][v]:
...             ans[t][v][c] = {}
...     if not r in ans[t][v][c]:
...             ans[t][v][c][r] = p
>>> print ans
{25: {3.8: {1: {12: 13.2, 14: 15.3}, 6: {12: 13.8, 14: 15.1}}}}
```