# Best practice to get and set a value in multi-level dict

Tags: python, getter-setter, magic-methods, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking a Dictionary using a dot notation string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414821/checking-a-dictionary-using-a-dot-notation-string)

There is a multi-levels dict like this:

```
some_infomations = {
    "root":{
        "sub":{
            "more_deep":{
                "not_enough": "Some value",
                "another": "bla..bla"
            }
        },
        "more":{
            "more_deep":{
                "not_enough": "Some value",
                "another": "bla..bla"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a crumbs string such as `root.sub.more_deep.another`, is there a simple and good way to do the work just like `eval("some_infomations[root.sub.more_deep.another] = some_value")`?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12414821/1639625

Answer (score 1):

Posted here mostly for fun, but also because `reduce` has a lot more use than most people give it credit for...:

```
from operator import getitem
def dot_get(your_dict,s):
    return reduce(getitem, s.split('.'), your_dict)  

d = {'foo': {'bar': {'baz': 1}}}
print dot_pull(d,'foo.bar.baz')
```

**EDIT** -- Apparently this is how OP did it in the previous question that I didn't read quite carefully enough,  although OP used `dict.get` which will suppress a KeyError.

To set an item, you'd need to split off the last element, and get the one above it:

```
def dot_set(your_dict,s,v):
    head,tail = s.rsplit('.',1)
    dot_get(yourdict,head)[tail] = v
```

Comment: I don't know how to format my answer properly, I've pasted it here:

https://gist.github.com/veverjak/72fa753f5e4234647835